# Print man pages with fixed width

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, man, text-formatting

With the example command

```
man apropos > outputfile
```

a text file is generated which contains the formatted `man` page of `apropos` (with some little differences with respect to `man apropos` directly printed on screen, such as bold characters).

But I would like to manually set the maximum line width of the generated output file, so that all the paragraphs will be justified to that width.

`man` pages are created through `groff`: for example, I tried to put `.ll 50` before a paragraph of the original `.gz` `man` source text file, but it is trivial if I need to work on several `man` pages. Moreover not all the characters are recognized:

```
apropos.1:45: warning: can't find character with input code 195
apropos.1:45: warning: can't find character with input code 168
apropos.1:47: warning: can't find character with input code 178
apropos.1:131: warning: can't find character with input code 169
```

So, I wonder if a more straightforward method exists. How to modify the maximum line width, during the creation of an `outputfile`? Is there some specific command?

---

**Edit**:

(All the following considerations are about Ubuntu 18.04: I can no more test them in previous versions, included the 14.04 of the above question.)

As regards a one-line temporary solution, if `MANWIDTH` has not been already exported with a custom value, there is no difference between

```
$ MANWIDTH=60 man apropos > outputfile
```

and

```
$ COLUMNS=60 man apropos > outputfile
```

The first one, using `MANWIDTH`, is however better in principle.

---

**Edit 2** (not strictly related to the question):

To make instead a permanent width setting to be applied to any manpage printing, it is necessary to **export** the desired value of the variable. With:

```
$ export MANWIDTH=60
# zero or more additional lines
$ man apropos > outputfile
```

`man apropos` will be printed with the same width regardless of any terminal window resizing. Instead,

```
$ export COLUMNS=60
# zero or more additional lines
$ man apropos > outputfile
```

will provide the same result as before only if the terminal window is not resized between `export` and `man <page> > outputfile`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your `input code` errors `195 168`  could be è in UTF-8. Is the man page in English? What's your man implementation? What's your locale?

Comment: the system is Ubuntu 14.04 (version from `man man` is 2.6.7.1). The man page is in Italian and it is UTF-8. What do you mean by locale?

Comment: What's the output of `locale`? and `locale charmap`?

Comment: `locale` output: `LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"`


`locale charmap` output:
`UTF-8`

Comment: I can't reproduce Ubuntu 14.04 with that same Italian man page with that same locale. Maybe something special in your environment. Do you get the error with `env -i  LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 man apropos`?

Comment: Don't worry; it is not a great issue; with the commands in your answer, I don't get any character error. Anyway, `env -i LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 man apropos` produces `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)` and then the man page appears (without errors, it seems).

Comment: Do you get those errors when you run `man apropos`? Or is it that you did `groff -Tascii` instead of `groff -Tutf8`?

Comment: Yes the _terminal not functional_ is from `less` because `TERM` is not set. I meant `env -i LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 man apropos > output` (or `| head`).

Comment: Ok! `env -i LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 man apropos | head` did not give any error. The same is for `groff -Tutf8`. The errors appeared only with `groff -Tascii`.

Comment: Knowing how to set the man page rendering width can be ergonomically helpful. Optimal readability is thought to arise at between 55-100 characters per line (see [1](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability), [2](http://www.danielbough.com/blog/2014/02/readability-characters-per-line/), [3](http://www.benshoemate.com/2013/08/02/optimum-web-readability-max-and-min-width-for-page-text/), [4](https://www.paulolyslager.com/optimal-text-layout-line-length/)) so setting [`$MANWIDTH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263594/6860) to, say, 80, can improve readability on very wide screens.

Comment: The last paragraph in your edit isn’t entirely correct: `COLUMNS=60 man apropos` does not work if `MANWIDTH` is already set. `MANWIDTH=60 man apropos` would work.

Comment: @MarcelM I hope that the new edit is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `MANWIDTH` environment variable:

```bsh
MANWIDTH=60 man apropos > apropos.txt
```

The manpage for man 2.7.4 says:

> If  $MANWIDTH  is  set,  its value is used as the line length for which manual pages should be formatted.  If it is not set, manual pages will be formatted with a line length appropriate to the current terminal (using the value of $COLUMNS, an ioctl(2) if available, or falling back to 80 characters if neither is available).

That is, it overrides both `COLUMNS` and the `ioctl` value. I prefer to not rely on modifying `COLUMNS` (although it does work here) since its value is updated dynamically every time the window size changes.

Using `MANWIDTH` instead of `COLUMNS` also allows you to make the change permanent by adding a line such as `export MANWIDTH=60` to your shell startup file.

Comment: Excellent job. I didn't want to change COLUMNS either, and MANWIDTH works a treat in RHEL5. Cheers.

Comment: A note to readers: you may need to use `export MANWIDTH=60` if setting this in your `~/.bashrc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173376/82216 . Also, consider wrapping `man` in a function to set MANWIDTH depending upon your terminal width, as suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Man_page&oldid=496767#Page_width) on the Arch wiki.

Comment: @Marcel M Thank you for your very precise answer. Can you please read the update in the question and edit your answer to include the fundamental suggestion about `export MANWIDTH=60`?

Comment: @BowPark I wrote the answer without `export` because you asked about a temporary solution: "How to modify the maximum line width, **during the creation of an outputfile?**" (emphasis mine). You may even want to revert your edit as it doesn’t add to the question. (A comment is more appropriate.)

Comment: @MarcelM Actually you are right. I edited the question accordingly. I wrote a second edit with the `export` statements because in a comment it would be almost unreadable (not being possible to create newlines).

Answer (score 11):

Try setting the `COLUMNS` environment variable. Works for me with `man` from `mandb` 2.7.0.2 on Debian with `groff` 1.22.3.

```
$ COLUMNS=60 man apropos | head
APROPOS(1)          Manual pager utils          APROPOS(1)



NAME
       apropos - search the manual page names and descrip‐
       tions

SYNOPSIS
       apropos [-dalv?V] [-e|-w|-r]  [-s  list]  [-m  sys‐
```

```
$ COLUMNS=70 man apropos | head
APROPOS(1)               Manual pager utils               APROPOS(1)



NAME
       apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions

SYNOPSIS
       apropos  [-dalv?V] [-e|-w|-r] [-s list] [-m system[,...]] [-M
       path] [-L locale] [-C file] keyword ...
```

With the version on Ubuntu 14.04, I need to write it:

```
COLUMNS=60 < /dev/null man apropos | head
```

There, `man` seems to disregard the `COLUMNS` environment variable if stdin is a terminal (it then queries the terminal device for the terminal width).

You can also try:

```
s=$(stty -g); stty cols 60; man apropos | head; stty "$s"
```

Which with `zsh` you can shorten to:

```
STTY='cols 60' man apropos | head
```

---

You could do it by invoking `groff` by hand as:

```
gzip -dcf "$(man -w apropos)" |
  groff -ekpstR -mtty-char -mandoc -Tutf8 -rLL=60n |
  col -bpx
```

where `groff` options are:

```
# Native groff Options

-e     eqn      (equations)
-k     preconv  (encoding for groff)
-p     pic      (pictures)
-s     soelim   (.so requests - source file)
-t     tbl      (format tables)
-R     refer    (bibliography)

# Transparent Options

-mtty-char
      Overrides  the  definition of standard  troff characters  and
      some groff characters for TTY devices. The optical appearance
      is  intentionally inferior  compared to  that  of normal  TTY 
      formatting to allow processing with critical  equipment.

-mandoc
      Use this file  in case you don't know  whether the man macros
      or the mdoc package should be used.    Multiple man pages (in 
      either format) can be handled.

-R     utf8     (output-encoding)


-r     LL=60n   (Number of LL registers)
```

Your *can't find character with input code* errors were because you used `-Tascii` instead of `-Tutf8` and didn't use `-k` to pre-process the files with `preconv`.

Comment: I tried the same command: `COLUMNS=60 man apropos | head`, but unfortunately the output width is all the screen width. Can I set the variable `COLUMNS` elsewhere or in other way?

Comment: Try `COLUMNS=60 < /dev/null man apropos | head`. Looks like on Ubuntu 14.04, it doesn't trust `COLUMNS` if stdin is a terminal (and gets the width from the terminal device).

Comment: Maybe it is like you supposed. And now it works, thank you!

Comment: Added some `man` information for options. I do not quite get what the `-rLL=60n` does though ...

Comment: @ibuprofen, see `info groff Options` and follow-up footnote.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `fmt` command, which as far as I know is present in any Linux distribution.

```
man apropos | fmt -w 70
```

will wrap up lines at 70 characters.

Comment: yes I have it, thank you, it works and it is pretty useful, but I need a **justified** text and it simply wrap up lines instead.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed up that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fold`

```
man cp | fold -w 20
```

will fold after each 20 characters(!). Note that this will cut words in two as the only option is "fold every 20 characters"

taking care of this, you might use `sed` as follows (with dynamic line length)

```
man cp | sed 's/.\{20\} /&\n/g'
```

will add a newline after 20 random characters followed by a space (i.e. new word). So lines might be longer than 20 characters (match is 20 characters then a space so a 26-character word would result in a 26-character line)

For omitting the last space in the `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\(.\{20\}\) /\1\n/g'
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your examples and they work, but - as written in a comment to dr01 - I need a justified text.