# Restrict the number of colums for man (or less)

Tags: man, less

I use man pages in the console a lot (no GUI), but the wide screen I use really has a lot of columns in text mode. The lines are too long and unpleasant to read.

Is there a way to limit the number of columns used by `man` (or `less`, which man uses internally)?

Comment: Similar: [Print man pages with fixed width](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222528)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Linux system that formats its manuals on the fly, set the `COLUMNS` or `MANWIDTH` environment variable to the width of lines that you'd like to have:

```bash
COLUMNS=72 man ...
```

You may want to set `MANWIDTH` to a sensible value in your shell's startup file as `COLUMNS` is used by many other programs besides `man`:

```bash
export MANWIDTH=72
```

---

On a system using [`mandoc`](http://mandoc.bsd.lv), use `man` with the option `-O width=72`, where `72` is whatever width you want to use.  The `mandoc` system uses a default width of `78`, so getting excessively long lines is usually not an issue; I'm just mentioning it here in case you want to modify the width to something even narrower.

On these systems, you could define an alias for your interactive shell like so:

```bash
alias man='man -O width=72'
```

... or a shell function that overloads the `man` name:

```bash
man () {
    command man -O width=72 "$@"
}
```

---

The poor man's option would be to pass the text through `fold` before piping it to `less`:

```bash
man ... | fold -s -w 72 | less
```

This folds the output of `man` at the last space on or before the 72nd column before `less` shows the output.  `fold` is a standard Unix utility.

The pipeline could be expressed in a shell function that overloads the `man` name like so:

```bash
man () {
    command man "$@" | fold -s -w 72 | less
}
```

Albeit not standard, the `fmt` utility is commonly available and may do a better job than the `fold` utility of folding long lines. Replace `fold -s -w 72` with `fmt -w 72` in the pipeline above to try it out.